# How to get the hostname for published services for particular arcgis credentials

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I have been creating a desktop application using Rest API.

I have ArcGIS account credentials on which I have posted some maps and layers. In my application, when I sign in to ArcGIS using my ArcGIS credentials, I need to know the hostname where my maps/layers are published. How can I get that. For one of my ArcGIS account the host name is like

```
https://services.arcgis.com/.........
```

and for another account it is like

```
https://services2.arcgis.com/.........
```

So, is there a way to figure out what is the hostname where my maps/layers are getting published?

I can definitely see the complete url of my maps/layers when I login to http://arcgis.com portal in browser and see "My Contents" which lists all my maps/layers and all that sort of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you login, and generates your token you can make the following query to see the url of your content.

http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/users/<username>?f=json&token=<generatedToken >

This will return you the json that contains the url of your published services.